# How to calculate previous business day in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How can I calulate previous business date in ActionScript? I am passing current server date time to flex via flashvars, but not able get logic of determining previous business day from the provided date? (Workdays being Monday-Friday)
Can you please help me in this regard?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at manipulating the date time classes?

Comment: @Nate, In existing application, they are using code like this to get previous business day, but its returning two days from today not one day... 

`code` var resultDate:Date = new Date(dt.fullYearUTC,dt.monthUTC,dt.dateUTC-1);
   while(resultDate.dayUTC == 0 || resultDate.dayUTC == 6)
   {
    resultDate = new Date(resultDate.fullYearUTC,resultDate.monthUTC,resultDate.dateUTC-1);
   }

Comment: code chunks in comments aren't the prettiest, make sure to edit your post! This might help: http://flash-creations.com/notes/asclass_date.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the time into Date object
2. Read the day of the week from it
3. Substract the 24hr's for each of the week day (e.g. if it is sunday then substract 48hrs if saturday just 24hrs)

best regards

Comment: Finding the business day is not the same as finding the week day, because you have to account for Holidays; which will most likely vary from business to business.

Comment: oh, yes? the question specifies the working week. The proposed solution also applies to bank holidays etc. when one will have a list of them and will try to match current date with stored as "holiday" and do the same (substract a day then check if "working" day).